# Access VBA, Unable to close the current form. Error 2585 This action can't be carried out while processing a form or report event

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

This should be so simple BUT!

My opening form displays a dropdown to select user name (filled from a select query) and an unbound text box to enter password. The password is compared with a fixed string and if it matches I need to close this form and open the main menu. There is also a button to close the whole system if you don't know the password.
The tab order is dropdown, text box, exit button.

After many varients of AfterUpdate, BeforeUpdate,lostFocus I put this code in the Got Focus event of the exit button, so that exit from the password box will trigger it. Each function sets the focus back to an appropriate incorrect entry but if all is correct the program flows to the last two lines.

```
    Private Sub btnExitAll_GotFocus()
        If PasswordNotOk() Then Exit Sub
        If UserNotOK() Then Exit Sub
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu"
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "Opening screen", acSaveNo
   End sub
```

The "Close" line fails with 2585. I have tried reversing the order of the last two lines.
I have even put the last two line in the click event of an temporary button, where they work exactly as intended!  So I tried calling that button's click event from this sub, but get the same error.
I have tried Unload me but that throws error 361 Can't load or unload this objectbut I just can't get this form to close itself.
If it helps, when I tried to do this in the before update event of the UNBOUD text box I got errors saying I couldn't do this before I saved the data.

Please someone what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the proper event for this: OnClick.

Comment: Attempting to code an authentication system in VBA is where you went wrong. Don't bother. It's not possible to make it secure even if you move away from your fixed string approach. If you need to secure an Access DB you do it with NTFS permissions, Either the user has permission to read\write the back end or they don't. Now your authentication is Windows.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments:

Gustav:  As I said I have tried using a button and it works, but for simplicity's sake I just want my non-technical elderly users to just press enter when the have entered their password. Why doesn't it work in this event?

Hackslash: Thanks very much.  I have copied your code but get the same error.

Your comments re security are noted, I am not trying to be secure. The computer is off line and in a room with secure access.  All those with access to the room have access to the computer but I have a user who has heard about GDPR and wants a password.

Comment: HackSlash.  For info the form isn't dirty, I put a break inside the IF loop and it is never reached.      What does this error mean and what causes it?

Comment: OK I have a work around. In Form Load I set Timer Interval to max (about 24 days) and put the Form Close code in the Sub Form_Timer().   
In the OnGotFocus event I do the password checking, and if its OK open The Main Menu. I then set the timer interval to 1 (millisecond) and the timer event closes the form.

But why does it through an error in anything other than a click or timer event?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `Me.Name` to close a form from itself. You might need to clear changes before you close.

```
Private Sub btnExitAll_Click()
    If PasswordNotOk() Then Exit Sub
    If UserNotOK() Then Exit Sub

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu"

    ' Discard changes so we can close without saving
    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        Me.Undo
    End If

    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
End Sub
```